# Transactional IMAP Mailbox access with Spring Integration

Tags: spring, transactions, imap, jakarta-mail, spring-integration

I have a very similar requirement like what is mentioned in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10935032/transactional-pop3-mailbox-access-with-spring-integration), but I am using Imap as follows my version of spring-integration is 1.0.4:

```
<mail:inbound-channel-adapter id="imapAdapter"
                                      store-uri="imaps://user:pass@domain:993/inbox"                                    
                                      channel="recieveEmailChannel"
                                      auto-startup="true"                                      
                                      java-mail-properties="javaMailProperties">
        <int:poller> 
        <int:interval-trigger initial-delay="1000" interval="2000"
        fixed-rate="true"/>
        <int:transactional transaction-manager="transactionManager" propagation="REQUIRED"/>
        </int:poller>
    </mail:inbound-channel-adapter>   
<int:channel id="recieveEmailChannel" />        
<int:service-activator input-channel="recieveEmailChannel" ref="emailReceiverService" method="receive"/>
<bean id="emailReceiverService" class="com.mydomain.email.in.DefaultEmailReceiverUtilService">
</bean>
```

**Question**
Does Imap support transactional in Spring-integration 1.0.4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the documentation, a transactional poller does NOT make an inherently non-transactional resource transactional. If an upstream resource (such as JDBC is used), the transaction is started with the poll and committed when the thread completes its work.

Starting with 2.2.0, the transactional element on the mail poller allows you to SYNCHRONIZE some action with such a transaction. This allows you, for example, to delete the email message if the transaction commits, but leave it in the mailbox if it rolls back.

Again, this does NOT make mail transactional.

Answer (score 1):

Same answer - mail servers don't support transactions.

Comment: Is there any options available like you have mentioned in the other thread "You'll need to implement your own transactional resource to wrap the mail server - transaction/intent log, failure recovery, etc", how to do that?